# Uploading a video to my YouTube account using YouTube API without requesting users permission

Tags: php, video, oauth, youtube, youtube-api

I am new with the YouTube API and I am trying to upload a recorded video from a website to my YouTube account through PHP. My issue seems to be with the OAuth acceptance to get a valid Access Token. What I want is for the site/server to authorise the request to upload to my YouTube channel, as opposed to get permission from the user to access their YouTube account, as they do not need to give any access to their account.

What I've tried:

- I've tried sending the request using an API Key but that just comes back with an error saying OAuth is expected.
- When using OAuth, it is prompting the user to allow the site to have access to manage their YouTube account, when I only want the site to access my account automatically. (The code for this was taken from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert -> Show Code -> PHP)
- I have generated an Access Token using https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/, and if I use the Access Token from there directly in my code (same as above, just replacing 'setAccessToken' to the string I get from OAuth Playground), it works as expected, however the token expires and then no longer works.

Any help or guidance on this would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Oauth2 and authorize your application once. Store the refresh token and then you will be able to use this refresh token in the future in order to allow users on your website to upload videos to your account.

Using the following will let you refresh the access token using your stored refresh token.

```
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($userCredentials['refresh_token']);
```